# problems inflating a view

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

Im trying to inflate a view which serves as a loading screen for my `glSurfaceView` while it swaps out textures during runtime (i know how to do it during my `onCreate` just fine). Its just a `RelativeLayout` with a progress bar in the middle and when its done with the swap it disappears, but its not inflating correctly.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading,null);
RelativeLayout loadingScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingScreen);
```

where loadingScreen is the id of the relative layout.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loadingScreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText android:layout_height="
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        wrap_content="" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For a test, I added an EditText above the following additional code to test it out:

```
EditText tester = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); //Now we have an object
    tester.setText("dfdfds");
```

and the error log:

```
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502): Failed to inflate
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.huskybus.CampusMapOpenGL
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at com.huskybus.Main.onCreate(Main.java:91)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     ... 21 more
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     at com.huskybus.CampusMapOpenGL.<init>(CampusMapOpenGL.java:101)
08-12 15:07:35.630: ERROR/ActivityThread(2502):     ... 24 more
08-12 15:07:35.637: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2502): Shutting down VM
08-12 15:07:35.637: WARN/dalvikvm(2502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.huskybus/com.huskybus.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.huskybus.CampusMapOpenGL
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.huskybus.CampusMapOpenGL
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.huskybus.Main.onCreate(Main.java:91)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     ... 11 more
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     ... 21 more
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     at com.huskybus.CampusMapOpenGL.<init>(CampusMapOpenGL.java:101)
08-12 15:07:35.653: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2502):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: Could you supply the stacktrace as well?

Comment: added, and included my test code.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading.findViewById(...) instead of just findViewById(...)

Comment: That seems to have worked, it doesnt crash anymore but i cant see it. Any idea how I can make it inflate over the current view?

Comment: Once a view is inflated into the object "loading", you would treat it just like any other layout object and use addView to append it to your existing layout. Inflating is just a quick and simple way of loading a complex layout in xml into memory instead of building it by hand in the code. If you wanted to replace all of the layout objects you have already loaded, I would simply get the top parent layout, remove all the children, and append "loading"

Comment: I dont need to remove the previous, think of it almost as a splash screen. I have my glSurfaceView set in my main.xml file, how would i use addView in this combination?

Answer (score 0):

i also have these kind of errors.i found that the error is come because of my text editor name is not match with the my text editor id.

Answer (score 0):

When you have inflatet the View you need to use that view when finding child views like this

```
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    loading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading,null);
    RelativeLayout loadingScreen = (RelativeLayout) loading.findViewById(R.id.loadingScreen);
```